# SQL Server 2014 stuck on uninstall

Tags: sql-server, uninstall, sql-server-2014

It must be around one hour and a half that I'm waiting for the uninstall process but it is frozen on this task:

[Can't Uninstall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWYSo.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: Check if the setup.log log something, it will help to identify the issue

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: check in temp/sqlserver*.log from memory